# Parse curl_exec response

Tags: php, curl

Almost whole day I'm struggling with this problem.

I'm using `$result = curl_exec($ch);` to read response and I would like to get Set-cookie header which look like that:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=05a0c785d8e2f4856a3f844e3694; Path=/qos; HttpOnly rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/qos; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 06-Sep-2012 10:50:20 GMT rememberMe=x+8X9hDZEUwM23osStzBmHs6FV/4VJAy18j4gjswG0H9wYKtOsSLu4p4XQ2KjLReNN4V2NokyjT66QkWzYetsde /Gbvmb9iJgV3VsuCvRgFpEFsduig5wHwu0YXjVgQWheiK87+5CNQE1X06z8mbPKu2GZUE/vwUUraR66ZAfxPdRKM24NKJ7HV4UIAPspudvCTJzFRqfkwb+pw cqnslyB6Rb/LB+pqHx2oshnINTwNd1E25+Zjs8qGQFQnHRvI4mRGF+BHC1JPGBV2GD9F7K29+szUlAGJhKr7FtOV1ELhN4JMqP4yuGDH0Dt9naLbRr6oFxxB 9t1+N5gHKVOE0vL5VM54Is5nAnWmhUrx9r3+R99We5phw7XuE1svlcOq2XrVeRJthMy3Xfp70cobUBdN/bOh5/ih9/wg3XwpagsGUKf1raP9mGO4ShDd+NFg8Z+eC+80Yt2wkS+7ZH/UGNh73LkdtCv6WlgFqiB/po20Lu+gCbDEceKt+lTNlU2c1; Path=/qos; Max-Age=15724800; Expires=Fri, 08-Mar-2013 10:50:20 GMT; HttpOnly
```

I would like to split them with ';' char.

EDIT:

Solutions below didn't work as I imagine. Maybe it's because I have other headers in my resoult:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2012 10:50:20 GMT
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=05a0c785d8e2f4856a3f844e3694; Path=/qos; HttpOnly rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/qos; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 06-Sep-2012 10:50:20 GMT rememberMe=x+8X9hDZEUwM23osStzBmHs6FV/4VJAy18j4gjswG0H9wYKtOsSLu4p4XQ2KjLReNN4V2NokyjT66QkWzYetsde /Gbvmb9iJgV3VsuCvRgFpEFsduig5wHwu0YXjVgQWheiK87+5CNQE1X06z8mbPKu2GZUE/vwUUraR66ZAfxPdRKM24NKJ7HV4UIAPspudvCTJzFRqfkwb+pw cqnslyB6Rb/LB+pqHx2oshnINTwNd1E25+Zjs8qGQFQnHRvI4mRGF+BHC1JPGBV2GD9F7K29+szUlAGJhKr7FtOV1ELhN4JMqP4yuGDH0Dt9naLbRr6oFxxB 9t1+N5gHKVOE0vL5VM54Is5nAnWmhUrx9r3+R99We5phw7XuE1svlcOq2XrVeRJthMy3Xfp70cobUBdN/bOh5/ih9/wg3XwpagsGUKf1raP9mGO4ShDd+NFg8Z+eC+80Yt2wkS+7ZH/UGNh73LkdtCv6WlgFqiB/po20Lu+gCbDEceKt+lTNlU2c1; Path=/qos; Max-Age=15724800; Expires=Fri, 08-Mar-2013 10:50:20 GMT; HttpOnly
```

And I need only Set-cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the soultion for that. One explode wasn't enough.

```
$parsedHeaders = http_parse_headers($result);
$set_cookie_header = $parsedHeaders['Set-Cookie'];
$cookie = $set_cookie_header[0];
$cookie = $cookie[0];
$cookie = explode('; ', $cookie);
$cookie = $cookie[0];
$cookie = substr($cookie, 11);
```

And the http_parse_headers I took from php.net examples and it looks like that:

```
function http_parse_headers( $header )
{
        $retVal = array();
        $fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header));
        foreach( $fields as $field ) {
            if( preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match) ) {
                $match[1] = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
                if( isset($retVal[$match[1]]) ) {
                    $retVal[$match[1]] = array($retVal[$match[1]], $match[2]);
                } else {
                    $retVal[$match[1]] = trim($match[2]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $retVal;
}
```

I hope that it will help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/explode) to split our string, like this:

```
$dataArray = explode('; ', $result);
```

and result $dataArray is array with all parts.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line to get an array of all elements of the `curl_exec()` result:

```
$parsedResult = explode('; ', $result);
```

Note that you can split the `curl_exec()` result with '; '.

You can then access the `Set-Cookie` value by doing this:

```
$setCookieValue = substr("Set-Cookie: ", "", $parsedResult[0]);
```

In essence, you take the first element of the $parsedResult array and remove "Set-Cookie: " from it.